# ArrayAdapter causing crash

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to implement an array adapter and I am getting an error everytime the activity starts.

here is my class and I have noted the line which causes the crash.

```
public class Attend extends Activity{

ListView amattendees;
ListView pmattendees;
String attendingAm[];
String attendingPm[];
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject json_event;
 String json_name = null;
 String json_badge_id = null;
 String json_venue_id = null;
 String json_event_id = null;
 String json_id = null;
 String json_date = null;
 String json_amLesson = null;
 String json_pmLesson = null;
 String json_youtubeid = null;
 String json_lessonHTML = null;
 String json_active = null;
 String json_created = null;
 String json_attending = null;
 String json_status = null;
 String fragmented = null;
 String json_title = null;
 String json_event_description = null;

 String[] participants = null;
 String setAttending_response = "Attend";
 String scannedBar = "default";
 SharedPreferences settings;
 String json_videopath;
 String str_accesstoken;
 Context context;
 VideoView youtubeVideo;
 String sAttending = "false";
 String home_venue_long = null;
 String home_venue_lat = null;
 private static final int REQUEST_BARCODE = 0;
 double my_longitude;
 double my_latitude;
 String json_venue_distance;
 String json_nearest_venue;
 String json_nearest_venue_logo;
 String json_nearest_venue_long;
 String json_nearest_venue_lat;
 String  json_participants_arr[];


 public String[] createArrayFromJSON(JSONArray json_array_participants){
      String json_participants[] = new String[json_array_participants.length()];
      json_participants_arr = new String[json_array_participants.length()];
 for(int i = 0; i < json_participants.length; i++){
     try{
         json_participants[i] = json_array_participants.getString(i);   
         json_participants_arr[i] = json_array_participants.getString(i);  
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
         e.getStackTrace();
        }
  }
 return json_participants;
 }



 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.attend);            

        amattendees = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.amattendees);
        pmattendees = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.pmattendees);



         try{
                //get the JSON values from the URL.
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://ajsonfeed.com?hi=23849348934");


               json_event = json.getJSONObject("event");
               json_name = json_event.getString("name");
               json_status = json.getString("status");
               json_badge_id =  json_event.getString("badge_id");
               json_venue_id = json_event.getString("venue_id");
               json_event_id = json_event.getString("event_id");
               json_id = json_event.getString("id");
               json_date = json_event.getString("date");
               json_amLesson = json_event.getString("amLesson");
               json_pmLesson = json_event.getString("pmLesson");
               json_youtubeid= json_event.getString("youtubeId");
               json_lessonHTML = json_event.getString("lessonHTML");
               json_active = json_event.getString("active");
               json_created = json_event.getString("created");
               json_attending = json_event.getString("attending");
               fragmented = json_event.getString("fragmented");
               JSONArray json_array_participants = json_event.getJSONArray("participants");   

               createArrayFromJSON(json_array_participants);


                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
```

this line crashes it.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, json_participants_arr);
```

.

```
 }






}
```

Error log from logcat:

```
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.jujitsu.app.com/org.jujitsu.app.com.Attend}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:47)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:169)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:138)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at org.jujitsu.app.com.Attend.onCreate(Attend.java:124)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
04-12 16:58:32.683: E/AndroidRuntime(7920):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: post the crash stacktrace from the log.

Comment: I added the stacktrace now. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                      createArrayFromJSON(json_array_participants));
```

and move this inside json's `try` block

Comment: sorry looks like stackoverflow removed my tags. I am already doing it like that... Ill updated the post with a LogCat log and appended tags.

Comment: ah right cool cheers... it appears that that was not the problem itself... I think the JSONArray I am getting is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only thing there that *can be null is your json_participants_arr, so there must be something about it that the ArrayAdapter constructor doesn't like.  It's initialized in your try/catch. Have you looked into that catch stacktrace to see if it's failing for some reason?

Comment: Maybe I am declaring the Json type wrong.. this is what I receive from the json feed: Response:
{
    "event": { 
        .......some other stuff
        "participants": []
    },
    ...some other stuff
}

Answer (score 0):

You have a null pointer exception from `json_participants_arr` being null, probably because something threw `JSONException` which you pretty much catch and then ignore. (don't do that), take the try/catches out and see what exception you're getting.

Once you've gotten that straightened you'll also want to come back and fix it from making network requests on the UI thread (the jParser.getJSONFromUrl line, look at [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) or [async tasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)). depending on what OS version you're using this could actually be your underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this ...

```
String[] arrParticipants = createArrayFromJSON(json_array_participants);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, arrParticipants );
```